# How do I create new PDF file every time i iterate or loop through the documents list?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am new to PDF creation and I am following the existing code to create a pdf file. I am amending the existing code by creating a new pdf.

From the list of the documents, I am looping through each document and give it a new name.

How do I create a new PDF file every time I iterate or loop through the documents list?

resultCollection - Got the list of the documents

currentCompanySegmentsSetings - An object with the details

creatingTableOfContent - table content

**What I have tried**

```
foreach (var item in resultCollection)
                {
                    var guidID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var newFileName = $"{currentCompanySegmentsSetings.FriendlySegmentName}-{Translator.TranslateDocumentType("invoice", currentCompanySegmentsSetings).ToLower()}-{guidID}-{message.documents.First().AccountNumber}.pdf";
                    outputFileNames.Add(newFileName);

                    //Create PDF's and send to the location
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(currentOutputDirectory);
                    var firstDocsMetadata = resultCollection.First().MetaData;
                    string generatedPDFLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentOutputDirectory, newFileName);

                    var file = DocumentsToPDFDocs(financialDocument);
                    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(generatedPDFLocation, CreateEncryptionWriteProperties()));
                    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

                    //Bookmarks 
                    pdfDoc.GetCatalog().SetPageMode(PdfName.UseOutlines);
                    doc.SetMargins(22f, 22f, 22f, 22f);
                    doc.SetFontSize(8);
                    doc.SetFontColor(Color.BLACK);

                    //1.Create table of contents 
                    var tableOfContentTopMargin = 176;
                    Table tableOfContent = creatingTableOfContent(file, currentCompanySegmentsSetings);
                    tableOfContent.SetDestination("p" + "index");
                    doc.Add(tableOfContent.SetMarginTop(tableOfContentTopMargin));

                    //How do i continue from here to create pdf to the directory

                    message.FinancialDocumentAttachments.Add(new MessageQueueAttachment()
                    {
                        Location = documentPath,
                        IsNew = true,
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid()
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to create a separate PDF file for each `item` in `resultCollection`.

You already generate a filename for each file:

```
var newFileName = ...
string generatedPDFLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentOutputDirectory, newFileName);
```

And you make a new `PdfDocument` and `Document` instance, to be written to a file with that filename:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(generatedPDFLocation,
    CreateEncryptionWriteProperties()));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
```

Then just add content to the `Document` instance (or to the `PdfDocument`). I assume that content is in the `item` or `resultCollection` somehow.

```
doc.add(new Paragraph("content for this document"));
```

Finally, close the document which will flush the PDF file to disk.

```
doc.close();
```

The next iteration of the `foreach` loop will generate a different filename and thus the next document will be written to a different file.

Answer (score -1):

You're using:

```
var firstDocsMetadata = resultCollection.First().MetaData;
```

When it should be:

```
var firstDocsMetadata = item.MetaData;
```

Since you're iterating the `resultCollection` and `item` is the element that is obtained in each loop.

Comment: That is not correct as he is not using the variable "firstDocsMetadata" anywhere

Comment: resultCollection got all the documents i want. Metadata it is an object which got all the data for that particular document. Not sure if am making sense